# How to add semi-colons and remove line breaks from RichTextBox?

Tags: c#

*I have a rich text box and on richtextbox I have below text *

***result:**

```
  ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" ADD ("FIELD_A6" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE)

  ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" DROP ("FIELD_A3")

  ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A2" VARCHAR2(20))

  ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A4" NUMBER(5,2))

  ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A4" NOT NULL ENABLE)

  ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A5" NULL)
```

**is there any way to get the result with one line break also end with semi-colon for each line?:**

**expected result:**

```
  ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" ADD ("FIELD_A6" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE);

  ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" DROP ("FIELD_A3");

  ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A2" VARCHAR2(20));

  ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A4" NUMBER(5,2));

  ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A4" NOT NULL ENABLE);

  ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A5" NULL);
```

Comment: What have you tried? We cannot help if we do not know the method of how you are trying to modify your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way:

```
string text = richTextBox1.Text;
richTextBox1.Text = "";

string[] splitted = text.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (string line in splitted)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + line.Trim() + ";" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```